# Finding the probability density function for a series of RV - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X_1\sim Uni([0,1])$.
>
> We'll define a series of random variables -
>
> We'll choose a random point on the segment $[0,X_1]$ and call it
>   $X_2$, then choose $x_3$ randomly on the segment $[0,X_2]$ and so on.
>
> Find $f_{x_n}$.

What I did was as follows:

$$f_{X_n|X_{n-1}^{=x}}=\frac 1 {x}$$

So, from the law of total probability:

$$f_{X_n}=\int_0^1 f_{X_n|X_{n-1}^{=x}}\cdot f_{X_{n-1}} dx$$

(the integral is supposed to run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ but the random variables get values in the range of $0$ to $1$).

Trying to solve by induction, I first wanted to see what $f_{X_2}$ looks like.
$$f_{X_2}=\int_0^1 f_{X_2|X_1^{=x}}\cdot f_{X_1} dx = \int_0^1 \frac 1 x dx=\ln{x}|_0^1$$

Giving me the unpleasent result of infinity.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, your lower bound is wrong. When you tried for $X_2$, it should be $\int_{x_2}^1 \frac{1}{x_1}\,dx_1$.

Comment: This exact model was asked about on the site in the last few days.

Comment: @Did Okay, I found it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_n$ be i.i.d. Unif($[0,1]$), and let $X_n=Y_1\cdot Y_2\cdots Y_n$. These $X_n$ are distributed exactly the same as the ones in your problem.

Writing $-\log X_n=\sum -\log Y_i$, we can see that $-\log X_n$ is equal to a sum of iid exponential random variables with unit means. This [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Generating_gamma-distributed_random_variables) that $-\log X_n$ has the gamma distribution $\Gamma(n,1)$, which has a pdf of $\frac{x^{n-1}e^{-x}}{(n-1)!}$. Applying the transformation $f(x)=e^{-x}$ to $-\log X_n$, and using the change of variables rule, we get that $X_n$ has a pdf of $$\Big|\frac{-1}x\Big|\cdot\frac{(-\log x)^{n-1}\cdot e^{-(-\log x)}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{(-\log x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$